# Picasa Api for Android not found

Tags: android, api, picasa

I´m trying to follow the step by step guide on this page: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=nl-NL

So, when trying to import the following:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.*;
```

It´s missing the API I assume, if I try to download it here it gives an error: http://code.google.com//code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list

Anybody who has a working link, or am I using a depreciated way of using picasa for my Android App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you wrote is wrong?

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list